# How to resolve IMPORTRANGE access permission issue in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am encountering an issue in Google Sheets while utilizing the IMPORTRANGE function across two sheets, both of which I am the owner of. Whenever I attempt to import data, I am greeted with the error message: "You don't have permissions to access that spreadsheet."

Here's the formula I am using:

`=importrange("URL_of_the_sheet","A2:A980")` 
I have verified that I am logged into the correct Google account, and have tried refreshing the browser and the sheets, re-adding the IMPORTRANGE formula, and even creating new sheets to test the function. Despite these efforts, the error persists.

Is there a known resolution to this issue, or any additional troubleshooting steps I might have overlooked?

Comment: any chance the sheet(s) are in excel import mode(you can see this green `.XLSX` symbol on *top-left* beside sheet name) and not `saved as google sheet`?!